# Redirect webform using IF statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, webforms

I'm working on a simple asp.net webform application
I want to redirect to another webform base in if statement
if the text of the label is m, directed to searchers form
and if the text of the label is a, directed to tasks form,
below is my code, but it doesn't direct to any form.

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

       sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from USRS where Uname='" + txUser.Text + "' and Psw='" + txPass.Text + "'", conn);
       dt = new DataTable();
       sqlda.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0 )
        {
            Label2.Text = "ok";
            type = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            Label1.Text = type;
            if(Label1.text == "m"){
            Response.Redirect("~/Srearcher.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text = "UserId & Password Is not correct Try again..!!";
        }
       

    }
```

Comment: Typo? text with caps T in your condition, it should be  `Label1.Text == "m"`

Comment: 1. Is "Srearcher.aspx" a typo? 2. You should definitely **not** be building your SQL like that. Look up parameterization 3. Is that label *exactly* equal to "m"? Are you certain there are no spaces or other characters? 4. Please post your *actual* code. `text` is capitalized, so there's no way this even compiles 5. I see nothing to do with redirection with "a"

Comment: Maybe your code bombs before you get to Response-Redirect - use a try catch.  And I dont see where you are opening connection, also using statements are better for ado.net

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection DBConn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                DBConn.ConnectionString = "your connection string here";//better to have a reuseable method here to retrieve
                DBConn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from USRS where Uname='" + txUser.Text + "' and Psw='" + txPass.Text + "'", DBConn))
                {
                    sqlda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Label2.Text = "ok";//maybe put in a updatepanel
                var type = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                Label1.Text = type;//maybe put in a updatepanel
                if (Label1.Text == "m")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Srearcher.aspx");//spelled correctly?
                }
                else
                {
                    Label2.Text = "UserId & Password Is not correct Try again..!!";//maybe put in a updatepanel
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //do something here - possibly log exception?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why the OP should "try this"? This answer would be better if you explain what you changed and why

Comment: I added comments to his question above - also added comments to the code?